# Biology progress and bioethics

Tags: philosophy-of-science

As I had said in the last question, I'm involved in a personal work in which I have to do a brilliant presentation on **tissue regeneration using embryo cells**. In the presentation there are a part of biology and a second part of **bioethics** and philosophy. My problem regards this last part (this is the reason I'm asking to the experts). I have thought on the possibility of linking the discussion that involves embryo cells with the concept of "person". So starting from this idea I would do first a explanation of the reasons of the debate (**is embryo a person?**) regarding embryo cells then start to talk about a philosopher that had talked about "person". I thought about **Mounier** and his **personalism** but I'm really  doubtful. What is your opinion about my idea? ***Can you suggest me better ideas that permit me to do a coherent and very interesting presentation?*** (sorry if my question seems too similar to the previous one and sorry for my english) Thank you in advance for your precious suggestions!!

Comment: Don't know about ethics, but when I'm on the receiving end of the health care system, I want them to use every scrap of available knowledge and technology on my behalf. I don't care where they got it ... Nazi experiments, dead babies, whatever. Just heal me. And I suspect most people agree, once they are the ones under the knife.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can offer a discussion on the issue of embryos and personhood; however, I have not kept  track of specific names of the philosophers' works that I have read on this topic.  I hope this will provide you with thought-provoking points to consider as you develop your presentation - it is a truly interesting and important topic.

**To summarize this discussion,** by the argument I will lay out (that if it is X at the end, in the absence of a distinct change, then it must be X from the start), there is not a good criteria for terminating another human's life at any developmental stage to use its cells.  The term personhood is inadequate, and more objective terminology should be used in order to successfully address these ethical and legal topics.

**Person / Non-person is a binary distinction.**  (There's no validity to "half-person" or "3/7ths person.")

["Person" has many different interpretations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personhood#Humans), even referring to adult humans;  historically, often the adult males of the ruling class were the only "persons" in a society.  [The fact that even in the US, women were denied full "personhood" within the last century](http://php.med.unsw.edu.au/embryology/index.php?title=Timeline_human_development#Week_1) makes it clear that the term fluctuates based upon current societal attitudes and politics.  It also morphs depending on the context in which it is used, and in some cases can even be defined by the desire of another human being.

It seems illogical (and unethical) that the definition of a **rightful member of our species** is allowed to morph depending on swinging attitudes and politics.

Scientific objectivity is a key in moving away from these fluctuating definitions.  So as definitions have shifted from white adult men being the only "persons" to *defining person as a living human being*, it's become even more critical to define "living human being."

**Human / Non-human is also a binary distinction.**

With binary definitions:

*If something is X at the end of a time interval, then either it must **become X during** that interval, or else it must have been X **from the start**.*

Therefore, starting with the premise that all adult humans are persons:

*If a human adult is a person, then either he/she **became a person at some moment**, or he/she **was a person from the start** of his/her individual lifetime.*

Then, becoming X requires a distinct change.

An individual living human being's natural development proceeds uninterrupted from zygote through adult senescence, given adequate nutrients and environment.  [The embryo is just one stage in this life cycle of a living human organism.](http://php.med.unsw.edu.au/embryology/index.php?title=Timeline_human_development#Week_1)

When you zoom in and look carefully, it is obvious that all development is gradual- physiologically, genetically, biochemically, anatomically - from the formation of the independent, genetically-unique zygote through adult senescence. (Look at the above link and see how slowly we change - and remember that these are a small number of stop-motion frames over 9 months of gradual development in gestation.)

**There are strong scientific arguments** that no single defining moment of change in the life development of an individual organism is significant enough of a change to demarcate a change in status to toggle from "not a human life" to "human life." Nor from "not a person" to "is a person."

- Commonly birth is used, but it is a gradual process of several hours to several days, with a spatial displacement of almost 2 feet. At what moment is it a human life or a person? Out with cord cut? Without it cut? Only head out? Cervix dilated?
- Birth also has almost nothing to do with the organism's developmental stage; a 26-week old pre-birth fetus is developmentally identical a 26-year old post-birth infant.
- Cognition is also a very gradual development that can vary widely between individuals. Discussions on this have very diverse opinions, but adults who cannot sense pain or adults who are unconscious are not denied personhood based upon those factors alone.  Therefore they are inadequate factors to define the initiation of personhood.

One way to approach this is to **consider how our discussions on this topic will change as technology advances**.  Right now, age of viability (able to survive outside the uterus) is somewhere around 23 weeks.  It used to be higher, and soon it will be lower.  Does technology change the definition of person?

**I would propose** that because the definition of "person" cannot allow for ambiguity and gray-zones (lacking a clear definition of "life" or "person" results in dangerous inconsistencies in discussions on policy, bioethics, and legality), then **if one cannot define criteria for a toggle point, there cannot be a solid argument for any toggle point.** Therefore, if none can be established, it defaults to the beginning of the line - the first point of formation of that unique individual human organism.

I argue that **the poorly-defined blanket term "person" should be eliminated, replaced with "human," and specific issues should be discussed directly** - using accurate terminology of the human developmental stage or attributes that are appropriate to the issue.

- "What do we use as criteria for ending a human's life?"  "When is it ethical to kill a human to harvest its cells?"  "Under what criteria can a female choose to end the life of her offspring?"

These are uncomfortable questions, but that's because the realities of these issues ARE uncomfortable.  We try to hide behind the word "person" to shield us from the discomfort, but we can't change reality to fit our comfort levels.

This would allow people of different belief systems to converse more logically about issues that absolutely must be discussed, without perpetuating the current cycle of conflict and misinformation.

To summarize, by the argument I laid out (that if it is X at the end, if there is no significant switch, then it must be X from the start), there is **not a good criteria for terminating another human's life at any developmental stage to use its cells**.  The term personhood is inadequate, and more objective terminology should be used in these discussions.

Something important to also consider is that this issue will soon be outdated. [Pluripotent stem cells are being generated from other sources, and it will soon replace the use of embryo tissues.](http://news.harvard.edu/gazette/story/2014/01/researchers-create-embryonic-stem-cells-without-embryo/)

I hope this helps generate some interesting thought and discussion, and give you some points to research and consider further as you develop your presentation.

Comment: Sorry if I comment only now when you have answered me long ago!!! I had been quite busy. Reading your very interesting answer (really!) I have a question. What are the strong scientific arguments you mention at the middle of your argomentation? I mean who had proposed this arguments?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are grasping *one* means of suggesting an ethical problem with the question of personhood and stem cells. One arena is a question of whether using the fruit of a form of research is immoral. This is called a "poisoned tree" problem. (One area where this is a problem is in the courtroom -- evidence acquired illegally is difficult if not impossible to admit -- and so is the evidence acquired based on that evidence). In science, however, it's just a reality we live with (as user4894 suggests in a glib comment to your question).

But that's not the only potential issue. A further issue is whether the specific use of embryonic stem cells in another person is immoral. One angle is the personhood question you raise -- which I assume is an ellipsis for this argument:

```
(1) It is wrong to kill a human person
(2) A human embryo is a human person
(3) Therefore, it is wrong to kill human fetuses
(4) You must kill human embryos are the origin of embryonic stem cells.
(5) Ergo, you must do something wrong  to produce human embryonic stem cells.
```

Doctor Whom's answer above gives an extended treatment of why one might accept this argument.

But I can think of several other questions that one could ask:

1. **A Question of Consent:** Is it moral to use human tissue in another without their consent? Also, do we need the consent of the parents of the embryo to use their tissue for this? What sort of disclosures are necessary and to what extent do they take place?
2. **GMO**: Recent studies have shown the cells of babies in their mother's bodies -- specifically there are studies that show these cells healing damaged tissue in areas like the heart. Can we insure that embryonic stem cells do not mingle with the cells of the host in unexpected ways? (this is an analogue of an argument against GMOs). Why should we glibly allow this when not allowing GMOs?
3. **Cadaver argument**: Would it be permissible to harvest cells from cadavers and use them in treating medical conditions in humans? Do embryonic stem cell lines count as "alive" to a sufficient extent to not be taboo? (i.e., are we avoiding the taboo by *lying* to patients about what we are doing?)
4. **Potential Immorality**: even if we're fine with benefiting from the fruit of the labor of "nazi research," it's not the same thing as directly participating in it. As long as the person question is open, it is morally unacceptable to do this. Here, this is an epistemic variant on the argument about personhood -- as long as we are debating it, it is immoral regardless of what the eventual resolution might be. (E.g., imagine eating a steak with a friend who tells you that he had two steaks in the freezer -- one beef and one human, and he's not sure which one he cooked. Would you put down the knife?)

These are just a few off the top of my head.